# How to get Multiple Results without using if elif statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to conditionally make a statement without using if elif statement in python to get multiple results. I am using Numpy and pandas at the current moment and I have found a way to use I just forgot the correct steps and don't know the name of this conditional statement.

```
grade = []
condition = [(if df['score'] => 90), 
             ((if df['score'] < 90) & (df['score'] >= 80)), 
             ((if df['score'] < 80) & (df['score'] >= 70)),
             ((if df['score'] < 70) & (df['score'] >= 65)),
             (if df['score'] < 65)]
results = {'A','B','C','D','F'}
grade.append(condition,results)
df['grade'] = results
```

This isn't right and I was hoping to get help on how to get this conditional to work. of if someone had a better way of doing it.
This is what I want:

```
score   grade 
  45      F
  79      C
  88      B
  56      F  
  94      A
```

Comment: [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)?

Comment: Code which doesn't do what you hope it should do is not a good way to explain what you actually want to happen. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @triplee I was just showing what I tried and see if someone has tried this method and knew where I messed up, Should I not show the code I used?

Comment: You need to show what you *do* want it to do; then someone may be able to help you modify your code to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David'],
                'score': [92, 85, 73, 60]})

# Define grade boundaries and corresponding labels
boundaries = [0, 65, 70, 80, 90, np.inf]
labels = ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']

# Compute grades based on score using NumPy boolean indexing
condition = [(df['score'] >= b) & (df['score'] < boundaries[i+1]) for i, b in enumerate(boundaries[:-1])]
results = np.select(condition, labels)

# Add grades as a new column to the dataframe
df['grade'] = results

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# df = pd.DataFrame({'score': np.random.randint(0, 100, 20)})
bins = [-np.inf, 65, 70, 80, 90, np.inf]
labels = list('ABCDF')
df['grade'] = pd.cut(df['score'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    score grade
0      56     A
1      90     D
2      29     A
3      78     C
4      82     D
5      50     A
6      89     D
7      26     A
8      36     A
9      89     D
10     34     A
11     49     A
12     14     A
13     86     D
14     34     A
15     25     A
16     95     F
17     15     A
18     36     A
19     32     A
```